# iCloud Keychain not restored when backup is loaded on other device

Tags: swift, icloud, keychain

In my Swift app I want to restore iCloud keychain data from a backup.
It works fine when the backup is restored on the same device where it was made. It also works using an encrypted iTunes backup. If I try to restore the iCloud on another device the values are just empty :(

I'm using the KeychainPasswordItem.swift wrapper from the Apple Doc.
I've set the query attributes to this:

```
    var query = [String : AnyObject]()
    query[kSecClass as String] = kSecClassGenericPassword
    query[kSecAttrService as String] = service as AnyObject?
    query[kSecAttrSynchronizable as String] = kSecAttrSynchronizableAny
    query[kSecAttrAccessible as String] = kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock
```

Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: You need to activate keychain sync in your device, I suppose

Comment: @Geru Yes I already did that.

Comment: According to discussion at forums.developer.apple.com https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/93373 this is not possible at the moment.